# UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT ABP Framework

Tags: abp

My client site is broadcasting from 10.0.0.70. api broadcasts from localhost:44376 on the same machine.
10.0.0.70:4200 opens but when I click login it leads to http://localhost:44376/account/login site but 500
Internal Server Error
I am getting an UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT error.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you changed the appsettings endpoints to 10.0.x from localhost **after** running dbmigrator causing your client still registered with localhost:4200 redirect uri.

That's why you're getting **UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT** error. I assume you are at the beginning of the project; you can delete your db and run db migrator again with your updated settings.

You can also check application logs for exact error messages; identityserver errors are logged detailed in log file.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when CORS URL defined in the ClientCorsOrign database table is not valid. eg `https:///www.domain.co.za` is valid while `https:///www.domain.co.za/app` is not valid. So to accurate identitify cause of this error, open Logs in Identity api, in my case the CORS url was invalid..